# What is the meaning of "lying over under all plain sail"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, phrasal-verbs

(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XI (last sentences), published 1892)

> Or was it really the eye, and not rather the heart, that identified that shadow in the dusk, among the shoreside lamps? I know not. It was Jim, at least; Jim, come for a last look; and we had but time to wave a valedictory gesture and exchange a wordless cry. This was our second parting, and our capacities were now reversed. It was mine to play the Argonaut, to speed affairs, to plan and to accomplish—if need were, at the price of life; it was his to sit at home, to study the calendar, and to wait. . .
>
> . . . and, as we swept under cloudy Tamalpais and through the roaring narrows of the bay, the Yankee blood sang in my veins with suspense and exultation.
>
> Outside the heads, as if to meet my desire, we found it blowing fresh from the north-east. No time had been lost. The sun was not yet up before the tug cast off the hawser, gave us a salute of three whistles, and turned homeward toward the coast, which now began to gleam along its margin with the earliest rays of day. There was no other ship in view when the Norah Creina, **lying over under all plain sail**, began her long and lonely voyage to the wreck.

What does *lying over under all plain sail* mean in this context? Is *lying over* a phrasal verb? What does it mean there?

Comment: Soon enough we can read The Wrecker in its entirety on ELL :)

Answer (score 1):

From the full Oxford English Dictionary...

> **lie** verb definition II.11.a
> (Of a ship) ***To be stationed in a berth or anchorage***
> *The Zebra lay just off the pier*  (D. G. Mitchell, Fresh Gleanings, 1851)

The "prepositionless" usage dates back to Old English, but ***over*** has been increasingly included. It's also worth noting that flexibility between ***lie*** and ***lay*** has led to the current position where the noun form is nearly always ***layover***. Which term extends well beyond the original nautical context - I used to work in the UK bus industry, where "layover" is any significant "idle time" for a passengerless bus between scheduled journeys. More generally, "layover" today is *a stop or stay in a place, esp. overnight; a halt, rest, delay*.

I assume (though I can't find an exact definition) that ***all plain sail*** here means ***in full rig,** with all sails set, ready to sail away at short notice*. Eventually leading to the modern figurative usage ***plain sailing = easy*** (of a task, problem-free, no encumbrances).

Comment: Merriam-Webster gives [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plain%20sail) for 'plain sail'. _Under all plain sail_ occurs a lot in the nautical novels of Patrick O'Brian.

Comment: Do ships at berth normally have those sails unfurled?

Comment: @KateBunting: Yes, I found that definition easily enough. But like TimR, I figured "berthed" ships wouldn't normally have all sails ***unfurled***, so I wasn't certain exactly what ***under** all plain sail* might imply. I'm ready to stand corrected, but I'm guessing all the sails are attached to their respective masts, but not actually unfurled (or the ship might get blown right out of the harbour, dragging anchors with it). But I'm no sailor, so what do I know?

Comment: I don't think _Norah_ was berthed. I did an Ngrams search for 'ship lying over'. Though a lot of the references are to a wrecked ship lodged at an angle, some are to a moving vessel leaning to one side.  "...No one was alarmed, but a ship lying over at an angle of 45 degrees made work about the deck very uncomfortable' and, from O'Brian again 'The frigate was racing along... lying over so that her deck sloped like a roof'.

Comment: @KateBunting: Well, we know the ship wasn't berthed at the point in time covered by the cited sentence, because she ***began her ... voyage*** then. If I was actually reading the book, I can't see it would make much difference to me whether the ship was "fully rigged, ready to set sail as soon as it grew light", or "leaning over". But now I'm being forced to think about it, I feel it's unlikely they'd have had ***all*** the sails fully unfurled overnight (in the dark! :) if there was enough wind to make the ship lean over very far. That sounds risky to me, but what do I know?

Comment: ...whatever - apart from the actual cited sentence, Google Books has no other instances of "lying over under all plain sail", nor does it have any instances of "lying over under plain sail" or  "lying over under all sail", so there's not really anything here a learner is ever likely to need to know for the future. Just get on and read the book, I'd say.

Comment: And hasn't the tugboat brought them out and given the three-whistle salute?

Comment: @TimR: Like I say, *IANAS* *(I am not a **Sailor**)*. I thought only ***steamboats*** had "whistles / horns" (same as steam-powered trains). But this question is starting to remind me of why I'd often rather just comment, not actually attempt to *answer*. Half the questions are more about real-world knowledge or opinions than "facts" about English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers For your bum steer with **layover** you must watch *Master and Commander: The Far Side of the World* and write a question submitted here about something somebody says :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi! I upvoted your good answer!

Comment: One remark may be allowed (though it doesn't fit the context): *My Bonnie lies over the ocean/ My Bonnie lies over the sea/ My Bonnie lies over the ocean/Oh, bring back my Bonnie to me* . . . - those were the days :-)!

Answer (score 1):

From Oxford English Dictionary (online), quotation date 1867

https://www.oed.com/search/advanced/Quotations?textTermText0=lie%20over&textTermOpt0=WordPhrase&quotDateFirstUse=all&quotDateFrom=1867&quotDateTo=1867&page=1&sortOption=AZ

> Lie over, a ship heeling to it with the wind abeam.
> W. H. Smyth & E. Belcher, Sailor's Word-book

The schooner *Norah Creina* is tugged out of the harbor of San Francisco. Outside the heads the wind is blowing fresh from the north-west, the tug casts off the hawser, gives a salute of three whistles and turns homeward. Now the *Norah Creina* turns into the wind, begins to *heel* (nautical term) = *lie over* or *lean over* under all plain sail and begins her long voyage to the wreck *Flying Scud*.

Comment: After a long search I found this definition.

Comment: Glad you found it. FWIW, to save time, I recommend starting future searches with high quality dictionaries like OED, Merriam-Webster, Collins, all of which have applicable definitions for "*lie over*".

Comment: What do you mean by FWIW? I've only found this in the OED online **that fits the context**, actually

Comment: This tells me you didn't look in Merriam-Webster for either "lie over" or "FWIW". I like the questions you've been posting about *The Wrecker*, but you should demonstrate in your questions that you've already looked the words up that you're asking about. The best way to do this is to quote the dictionaries you looked in, then explain why you're still unsure.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I looked up Meriam-Webster, Collins, OALD, Oxford Dictionary of English, Webster's Comprehensive Dictionary, Cambridge Dictionary and even the Oxford Dictionary English Dictionary (online). However, I couldn't find any definition that fitted the context, actually. So, I tried the Oxford English Dictionary (online) once again., and at last,  with great expenditure of time, I fortunately found the definition "Lie over, a ship heeling to it with the wind abeam". *That's the truth*.

Comment: You may say I should have looked up the Oxford English Dictionary (online) more exactly, but this is hairsplitting. Why should I know I can find this definition in this dictionary or would find a fitting definition at all? There is a point where this *looking up* comes to an end - and that is the expenditure of time *and* when you judge it impossible to find a solution.

Comment: OK. I accept that you looked in all these dictionaries, and I'm glad to hear it. Most people don't do even that much work. *My main point is that you need to say that in your question.* Two or three of your questions about this book looked to me like they were answerable with a quick dictionary search. I may have been wrong about that, but it's still *your job* as the person asking the question to show us that you've looked. Doing so attracts more answers, more upvotes, and fewer close votes. It's a win-win